# Can I replace Apc caching with file caching, and still benefit from Apc when present?

Tags: php, caching, apc, silex

I was thinking that maybe I could just forget about Apc, and simply use file caching (using .php files), because then I wouldn't need to think or check whether Apc is enabled or not, it would just work, and I would still benefit from Apc caching when it is present, because the .php files would be cached automatically.

- Is anyone already doing this? Does it work?
- Does this prevent the Apc cache-slams?
- Are there any downsides?

I found out some people in the Silex repository saying this was good, but I'm not sure if it was a very particular case.

Comment: Do you mean user data caching or the scripts itselves?

Comment: @DiegoAgulló I mean instead of using apc user cache (or redis cache, or whatever), write the data to .php files and require them. This way, if there is no Apc, it works as a filesystem cache. But if Apc is present, it works as Apc cache because the require should trigger the cache for the scripts.